# Linux ARM CONFIG_SMP=y on a uniprocessor system

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

What is the difference in linux booting sequence later, between a linux compiled with CONFIG_SMP=y and one with CONFIG_SMP=n

Comment: http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SMP.html

Comment: You have a single processor, so there is no difference.

Comment: If you know you have only one processor, it's better to say N.

Comment: nope if you want to make a generic image

Answer (score 2):

There are various low-level differences if you run a single-CPU system with CONFIG_SMP=y kernel. These will result in larger binary and degraded performance.

Roughly speaking: with SMP=n, the SMP synchronization primitives (widespread in kernel) compile to nothing, no instructions are generated. Similarly, PERCPU activities compile to nothing.

With SMP on, compile produces instructions which are executed e.g. to acquire and release locks. Similarly, PERCPU loops, which index from 1 to 1, are created around various kernel actions. IIRC, I saw increase in boot time and degraded dd micro-benchmark performance, roughly 10%.

Answer (score -1):

If yes, it enables multiple processors (if present) to be run during startup. So, no difference.

Comment: I have noticed that smp linux on a uni sends sgi to itself while nonsmp linux doesnot so there would be more diffs